# Updating the button element as a countdown timer through javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, element, setinterval, countdowntimer

I want to create a countdown timer which looks like an fps counter for webpage...
after hours of time spent i m not able to find out what is wrong.....help

```
<script>
    var myvar = setInterval(function () { startTimer() }, 1000);

    function startTimer() {
        var presentTime = 17 + ":" + 00;
        var timeArray = presentTime.split(/[:]+/);
        var m = timeArray[0];
        var s = checkSecond((timeArray[1] - 1));
        if (s == 59) {
            m = m - 1
        }
        //if(m<0){alert('timer completed')}

        var button2 = document.createElement("Button2");
        var interval = m + s;
        button2.innerHTML = Math.round(interval);

        button2.style = "top:0; left:0rem; height:10% ;color: black; background-color: #ffffff;position:fixed;padding:20px;font-size:large;font-weight: bold;";

        setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
        document.body.appendChild(button2);
    }

    function checkSecond(sec) {
        if (sec < 10 && sec >= 0) {
            sec = "0" + sec
        }; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
        if (sec < 0) {
            sec = "59"
        };
        return sec;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly does the code do that differs from the intended result?

Comment: Actually, having now had a quick glance, it appears that you have hard-coded the time to be `17:00` in your `startTimer`, so the clock will never update. Why are you hard-coding this value and not trying to update it each second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can find three errors that hinder your code from performing correctly.

**Multiple timers**

First off since you invoke both a `setInterval` in outer scope, and then a `setTimeout` after each performed iteration, you will end up getting many unwanted timer instances that will do some crazy counting for you.

I recommend you to scrap either one of these and stick with just one of them.
For my example i happend to stick with the `setInterval` since you're executing the very same method over and over any way.

**The initialization**

Since the `presentTime` is declared inside the `startTimer`-function it will be constantly overwritten with `17 + ":" + 00` (resulting in `"17:0"` btw).
This is solved by declaring it in the outer scope instead.

**Remembering the changes**

Finally you need to save the current state of `presentTime` after modifications. Just adding a `presentTime = [m,s].join(":");` at the end of `startTimer()` solves this.

```
var presentTime = "17:00";

function startTimer() {
    var timeArray = presentTime.split(/[:]+/);
    var m = timeArray[0];
    var s = checkSecond((timeArray[1] - 1));
    if (s == 59) {
        m = m - 1
    }

    var button2 = document.createElement("Button2");
    var interval = s;
    button2.innerHTML = m + ":" + s;

    button2.style = "top:0; left:0rem; height:10% ;color: black; background-color: #ffffff;position:fixed;padding:20px;font-size:large;font-weight: bold;";

    document.body.appendChild(button2);
    presentTime = [m,s].join(":");
}

function checkSecond(sec) {
    if (sec < 10 && sec >= 0) {
        sec = "0" + sec
    }; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    if (sec < 0) {
        sec = "59"
    };
    return sec;
}

var interval = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
```

Comment: thank you magnus for the detailed info where i was going wrong......
could you help me once more in gettting the colon in between mm:ss while updating in page...

Comment: Sure. You just need to `button2.innerHTML = Math.round(m+s);` into `button2.innerHTML = m + ":" + s;` and you're all set.
I'll update the answer with this code.

Comment: Please consider marking my answer as accepted if you feel it is a viable solution to your problem.